# Disk Cleanup Powershell script

Tags: powershell

I use this powershell script to clear the system drive (usually drive C). I store it in a USB drive and run it but I found it also tries to clean my USB drive. Please help how to limit the operation in system drive only.

> Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VolumeCaches*' | % {
> New-ItemProperty -Path $_.PSPath -Name StateFlags0001 -Value 2 -PropertyType DWord -Force
> };
> Start-Process -FilePath CleanMgr.exe -ArgumentList '/sagerun:1' ##-WindowStyle Hidden

Comment: Yes, I do and it is happening.

Comment: Do you have the option to disconnect/eject USB thumb drives before you run the process?